# Error establishing socket

Tags: java, sql-server, sockets, jdbc

Have a java program which is trying to insert about 150k records to sql server database and failing with the error below.

> [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket

Started seeing these errors after the increase in data volume i.e the number of inserts. The SQL Server connection works works fine.

I tried changing the JDBC string by setting Max connection pool as below

```
String DB_URL= "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.com:11111;SelectMethod=Direct;DatabaseName=DB1;Max Pool Size=100000"
```

Not sure how to fix this issue. Please need help on the same.

Comment: SQLServer 2000 Driver? I'm not sure but maybe you should start by using an up-to-date driver? Or do you still use SQLServer 2000?

Comment: Are you creating connection insert per each insert?

Comment: connection is created once and executing prepared statement with inserts/updates as batch

Answer (score 1):

The error says it cant open a socket. There is typically a fixed number of connections you can open, either you have exhausted that limit (check using admin console) or the server process is stuck in a bad state (try restarting the db server process)

Comment: Open and close connection after processing every 10k rows is it good practice??

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to do so? Have a look at flush that would probably be more useful. Every connection you open needs to be eventually closed even in case of a failure. Ideally you open and close a connection only once.

Comment: since I am trying to insert 150k records, maybe I am thinking the connections have to released by closing. But, from what you said it should not. Sunny, what to fush??

Comment: A flush is like a commit all pending transactions. You can issue it on the JDBC connection object. Have a look at the javadocs of the connection class for more details.6

Comment: Have Auto commit to true and is commits as well. Forgot to mention having this issue on prod server only. When I run this on my local machine connecting to prod it works fine. I tried calling Thread.sleep() for 10 sec after executeBatch of 10k records as well. Not sure what else to try. Please advice.

Comment: You still would benefit from flush.  Thread.sleep wont do anything useful. From your comments I understand that this is happening only in a certain environment. If indeed that is true you need to study that the nature of connectivity in that environment. There might be firewall rules that might prevent opening certain sockets from said hosts. Have a look at it from a network point of view. This is diverting from the original question a lot. You perhaps need to post a different question and close this one. Please post a link here if you do. It sounds like this question is no more relevant 2 you

Comment: ok will try with flush. Even on server the program was working fine until the volume increased. Once there was increase in volume(number of records) to process it started failing. Thanks, for trying to help. I really appreciate.

Comment: Thanks, for trying to help me. The program was loading sql server 2000 and 2008 drivers. I downloaded the new sql server driver and used only that. After that the program is running fine. Thanks, again for all your help